# Проблема с командой PECL в Windows: 'pecl' не распознается как команда

Tags: php, powershell, pecl

Я столкнулся с проблемой при использовании команды PECL в командной строке Windows для установки расширений PHP. При выполнении команды 'pecl install extension_name' получаю сообщение об ошибке 'pecl: The term 'pecl' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program'.

У меня установлен PHP и я добавил его директорию в переменную PATH системы. Кроме того, убедился, что MinGW установлен и доступен. Команда PHP работает без проблем, однако команда PECL не распознается.

Я попробовал перезапустить командную строку после внесения изменений в переменную PATH, но проблема осталась. Проверил правильность установки PHP и MinGW, все выглядит нормально.

Как я могу решить эту проблему и сделать команду PECL доступной для установки расширений PHP? Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Вот некоторая дополнительная информация:

Версия PHP: 8.2.6
Содержимое переменной PATH: C:\PHP
Спасибо заранее за вашу помощь!"

Comment: Установи WSL в Windows и работай в Ubuntu. Не сказать что проблемы исчезнут, но их решение будет более понятное и лаконичное. А здесь можно пытаться найти решение, но это не совсем рационально.